# Firebase Emulator Error: firebase-tools no longer supports Java version before 11

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, emulation, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase Functions, Realtime Database & Hosting in my firebase project. I installed & configured local emulator suit for my project. But when I am writing `firebase emulators:start` command in Visual Studio Code terminal to use emulator, it gives me below Error.

```
!!  emulators: firebase-tools no longer supports Java version before 11. Please upgrade to Java version 11 or above to continue using 
the emulators.
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.

Error: firebase-tools no longer supports Java version before 11. Please upgrade to Java version 11 or above to continue using the emulators.
```

I tried using `firebase emulators:start --only hosting` & `firebase emulators:start --only functions`. Both of them are working fine. But when
I tried `firebase emulators:start --only database` It gives me the same error.

To check the Java version installed in my windows 10 pc , I typed `java -version.` in my CMD. It gave me below output.

```
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am interpreting it as Java version 19 is already installed in my PC.

Please guide me the missing part because of which firebase gives the error for java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438409/firebase-tools-no-longer-supports-java-version-before-11-please-upgrade-to-java) here.

> firebase-tools is referring to the version of the JDK installed, not the version of Java runtime installed.

please have a look at this.